# Connection of weak and pointwise convergence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $Y_n:=v_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\xrightarrow{}Z\sim N(0,1)$ in distribution where $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a stationary sequence of real random variables with finite variance and $v_l$ is a appropriate standardisation.

Is it possible to assume that there exists a random variable $\tilde{Z}$ with $Y_n\xrightarrow{}\tilde{Z}\sim N(0,1)$ pointwise? Or do we have to change the probability spaces where $Y_n$ and $Z$ originate from as in Skorohod's representation theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: In general you cannot. Since you can have a sequence that converges in distribution to some law and not converging in probability to any random variable. Thus you cannot have almost sure convergence of the sequence.

Comment: @Bunder: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In general, convergence in distribution tells us nothing about the actual behavior of the random variable itself. Example:
let $X_n\sim N(0,1)$, and $Y_n:= (-1)^n X_n$ . Then $Y_n\overset{D}{\to} X$ , but $P(\omega: \text{$Y_n(w)$  converges } ) = 0$.